# Seeding identity data in EF core 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-identity

I'm trying to seed identity roles and users. I have the following:

```cs
public class AppDbContext : IdentityDbContext<User, Role, int>
{
    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options) : base(options) { }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Entity<Role>().HasData(new Role
        {
            Id = 1,
            Name = "SystemAdmin",
            NormalizedName = "SYSTEMADMIN"
        });

        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
}
```

This creates the role in the DB as expected, however the `NormalizedName` is left `null`, regardless of whether I specify a value or not. The same thing happens when trying to create a user with normalized properties.

How do I go about seeding identity data (roles, users) with normalized data in the relevant properties?

Worth noting I'm using:

- `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore` v6.0.8
- `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` v6.0.8

Comment: Have you checked the SQL that is generated when the migrations are applied?

Comment: @KieranDevlin Great question - the SQL shows that null is explicitly being inserted into that column: `INSERT INTO "AspNetRoles" (Id, ConcurrencyStamp, Name, NormalizedName)
VALUES (1, '6d688c6b-6ebd-43af-b9ec-f2d6b289e9c6', 'SystemAdmin', NULL);`

Comment: Have you tried putting the `base.OnModelCreating(builder);` on the line above the seed?

Comment: @OkanKaradag Thanks for your suggestion. This wasnt the problem - I simply hadnt created a new migration to apply the normalised names :facepalm:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was my mistake... I had created the first migration without specifying the `NormalizedName` value, then given it a value but not created a new migration to apply this change. So when I ran `dotnet ef migrate script`, it showed me the script for the first migration, and when I ran `dotnet ef database update`, it updated the database to apply only the first migration.

So the obvious fix to this was to create a new migration:

```
dotnet ef migrations add NormalizedSeedData
```

Then update the database with the latest migration:

```
dotnet ef database update
```